# Get the rank of a user between 6 others with 2 higher and 2 lower scores in a score table

Tags: mysql, sql, rank

I have a very simple MySQL table where I save highscores. It looks like that:

```
Id     Name     Score
```

So far so good. The question is: How do I get what's a users rank?and how can i get the users rank between some (like 2) users with higher and 2 users with lower scores when i have users `id`.

An Example

```
Id  Name    Score
1   Ida     100
2   Boo     58
3   Lala    88
4   Bash    102
5   Assem   99
6   cha     105
7   phib    30
```

In this very case, result would be like this:

```
Id  Name    Score
4   Bash    102
1   Ida     100
5   Assem   99
3   Lala    88
2   Boo     58
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know about `ORDER BY`?

Comment: i ment between others ; not exactly 6 others :)

Comment: i know about order by but this case cant solve with that

Comment: using union solves one side of problem.the other side is i dont have the score.i just have the id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
(select t.*
 from t
 where t.score >= (select t2.score from t t2 where t2.id = 5)
 order by score asc
 limit 3
) union all
(select t.*
 from t
 where t.score < (select t2.score from t t2 where t2.id = 5)
 order by score asc
 limit 2
)
order by score desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY` sorts your query result by the column of your choice, defaulting to ascending order. The proper query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] ORDER BY Score DESC
```

More information can be found [here](http://www.dofactory.com/sql/order-by).

Comment: i just have id not score

Comment: @user3084088 Not sure that is relevant, but in SQL it is pretty easy to go from `id` to `Score`...